# How to use css on site for modal

Tags: css, joomla

Hi I am using Artisteer to create my site styling for a joomla application I am working on, the site is at http://imsdrive.co.uk

I have added an addon that displays a warning message that the user is about to be timed out see [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/6bp6lu).

What I want is to modify the standard css that comes with the plugin for the modal window, to match that of my site, I have no idea how to use CSS (that's why I bought artisteer), any help please.

This is existing css for modal popup that comes with plugin:

```
.sessionkeepermessage h1,
.sessionkeeperexpired h1 {
text-align:center;
}
.sessionkeepermessage p.message,
.sessionkeeperexpired p.message {
text-align:justify;
}
.sessionkeepermessage button {
width:48%;
margin:0 1%;
float:left;
clear:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stock popup design is look like jquery lightbox.
Emmm, try to use Chrome Inspector -- it's first. Without it you won't be able to create normal modal window design.
Second -- you should know some basic css markup rules
Third -- I think, CSS changes for modal window should be pasted into /templates/imsdrive_public/css/template.css